# yield and update list doesn't work

Tags: python, yield

Basically I want this code to yield the element 0 of the list and update the list so next time it will yield the next element. Instead I get this error:

`"TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "`

```
import random

def deterministicNumber():
    return next(gener())

def gener():    
    listy = [10,12,14,16,18,20]
    while True:
        listy = listy[1:].append(listy[0])
        print listy
        yield listy[0]
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

```
listy = listy[1:].append(listy[0])
```

This line assigns `listy = None`, because `list.append` method operates in place and returns `None`.  Then in the next iteration of the loop, your `TypeError` is caused by accessing `None[1:].append(None[0])`

For a one-shot iterator on the list, you can simply use instead:

```
gener = iter([10,12,14,16,18,20])
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want an iterator that cycles repeatedly through your list.

You better use the function [cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) from the itertools module for this task:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> gener = itertools.cycle([10,12,14,16,18,20])
>>> def deterministicNumber(it):
        return next(it)
>>> for _ in range(10):
        print(deterministicNumber(gener))
10
12
14
16
18
20
10
12
14
16
```

Comment: ＋1  ah, yes actually that does looks like it was the real intention behind `listy[1:].append(listy[0])`.  good psychic debugging!

Answer (score 0):

No need to update the list.

```
def gener():    
    listy = [10,12,14,16,18,20]
    for item in listy:
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return the numbers forever.

```
def listy(array):
    i = 0
    while 1:
        yield array[i % len(array)]
        i += 1


for l in listy(['a', 'b', 'c']):
  print l
```

if you only wanted to do this one loop:

```
def listy(array):
    i = 0
    while i < len(array):
        yield array[i]
        i += 1

for l in listy(['d', 'e', 'f']):
  print l
```